# Padding value for the fancybox does not work as intended

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

For all my pictures I'm using fancybox without any white border, so I need as default padding `0`. I had some trouble to set it to `0`. First I tried to set it in the CSS class `fancybox-skin`. But that seems to work only if I use `padding: 0px !important;`. So I decided to set the default value within the js file `jquery.fancybox.js`. Not so nice, I would like more to set it within the CMS.

Now my problem: For one iframe I would need to set a border. Within Contao I have only one script call for all pages, so I can't set a fixed padding in that script call. So I want to add the padding value to the link and read it in the script. I tried to do that with the call of the fancybox script but I don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
        helpers : {
            title: {
                type: 'over'
            }        
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                    return false; 
            });
        },
        beforeLoad : function() {         
            this.width  = parseInt(this.element.data('fancybox-width'));  
            this.height = parseInt(this.element.data('fancybox-height'));
            this.padding = parseInt(this.element.data('fancybox-padding'));
        }
    });
});
```

Why do I need to transfer the width/height value within that script and that will work? Why doesn't it work with the padding value even I transfer it? And why does the `data-fancybox-group=` value works even it is not transferred in the script call?

Here's the example: http://www.schwarzwald-ferienhaus-imbirkenweg.de/

Use the button `Sofortangebot abrufen` to see it working.

Answer (score 2):

First, bear in mind that most settings can be changed within your own initialization script and most customization can be done through fancybox callbacks, so don't need to mess with the original fancybox js or css files.

Second, you can have global settings for all your fancybox elements and pass specific settings for some elements by using (HTML5) `data` attributes and apply those settings using `jQuery.extend()` within the `beforeLoad` callback so, having this html example :

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="01.jpg">one</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="02.jpg" data-padding="20">two</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="03.jpg">three</a>
```

**Notice** we added a `data-padding="20"` attribute to the second element.

Now, we could use this single script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        padding: 0, // set for all elements
        beforeLoad: function () {
            // check if current element has data-padding attribute
            if (this.element.data("padding")) {
                // get data-padding value 
                var p = this.element.data("padding");
                $.extend(this, {
                    // set padding as array 
                    // [top, right, bottom, left]
                    padding: [p, p, p, p]
                });
            }
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** while using `.extend()` we have to pass the `padding` value as an *array* `[top, right, bottom, left]` (you could pass a different value for each side of the element this way)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6ur01cs4/)**